# Html Rotativa NET CORE 6

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-core-6.0

I am working with a .NET Core 6 Web API and I am using Rotativa to generate reports. I am currently renouncing the creation of a dynamic grid with the data that comes from a stored procedure which is called in the controller and then I pass its result to said method that passes and then iterates and builds the html.

I'm building everything on the API side in C#.

I attach the code where I put together the HTML

```
public string GetHtml(List<ListaMovimientosArea> movimientosArea)
{
        string tablaHtml = "";

        foreach (var movArea in movimientosArea)
        {
            tablaHtml += String.Format
                ("<tr>" +
                    "<td colspan=\"1\">{0}<td>" +
                    "<td colspan=\"2\">{1}<td>" +
                    "<td colspan=\"2\">{2}<td>" +
                    "<td colspan=\"3\">{3}<td>" +
                    "<td colspan=\"3\">{4}<td>" +
                    "<td colspan=\"1\">{5}<td>"+
                 "</tr>",
                movArea.MovimientoId,
                movArea.NombreArea,
                movArea.FechaMovimiento,
                movArea.TipoMovimientoNombre,
                movArea.NombrePersona,
                movArea.MontoTotal
                );
        }

        string html = @"<!DOCTYPE html>
                    <html>
                    <head>
                        <meta charset=""utf-8"" />
                        <title>A simple, clean, and responsive HTML invoice template</title>

                        <style>
                            .invoice-box {
                                max-width: 800px;
                                margin: auto;
                                padding: 30px;
                                border: 1px solid #eee;
                                box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
                                font-size: 16px;
                                line-height: 24px;
                                font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                                color: #555;
                            }

                                .invoice-box table {
                                    width: 100%;
                                    line-height: inherit;
                                    text-align: left;
                                }

                                    .invoice-box table td {
                                        padding: 5px;
                                        vertical-align: top;
                                    }

                                    .invoice-box table tr td:nth-child(2) {
                                        text-align: right;
                                    }

                                    .invoice-box table tr.top table td {
                                        padding-bottom: 20px;
                                    }

                                        .invoice-box table tr.top table td.title {
                                            font-size: 45px;
                                            line-height: 45px;
                                            color: #333;
                                        }

                                    .invoice-box table tr.information table td {
                                        padding-bottom: 40px;
                                    }

                                    .invoice-box table tr.heading td {
                                        background: #eee;
                                        border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
                                        font-weight: bold;
                                    }

                                    .invoice-box table tr.details td {
                                        padding-bottom: 20px;
                                    }

                                    .invoice-box table tr.item td {
                                        border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
                                    }

                                    .invoice-box table tr.item.last td {
                                        border-bottom: none;
                                    }

                                    .invoice-box table tr.total td:nth-child(2) {
                                        border-top: 2px solid #eee;
                                        font-weight: bold;
                                    }

                            @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
                                .invoice-box table tr.top table td {
                                    width: 100%;
                                    display: block;
                                    text-align: center;
                                }

                                .invoice-box table tr.information table td {
                                    width: 100%;
                                    display: block;
                                    text-align: center;
                                }
                            }

                            /** RTL **/
                            .invoice-box.rtl {
                                direction: rtl;
                                font-family: Tahoma, 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                            }

                                .invoice-box.rtl table {
                                    text-align: right;
                                }

                                    .invoice-box.rtl table tr td:nth-child(2) {
                                        text-align: left;
                                    }

                            tr.spaceUnder > td {
                                padding-top: 10em;
                            }

                            tr.border > td {
                                border: solid;
                                border-width: 1px 0;
                            }
                        </style>
                    </head>

                    <body>
                        <div class=""invoice-box"">
                            <table border=""1"" cellpadding=""0"" cellspacing=""0"">
                                <tr class=""top"">
                                    <td>
                                        <table border=""1"">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class=""title"">
                                                    <img THERE IS A IMAGE>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr class=""information"">
                                    <td>
                                        <table>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    Caritas Argentina<br />
                                                    Diocesana Villa Maria<br />
                                                    Tel/Fax (0353) 4530388/4528919 <br />
                                                    Mexico 60 - 5900 Villa Maria (Cba.) <br />
                                                    e-mail: caritasvillamaria@hotmail.com
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>  
                                <table border=""1"">
                                    <tr class=""heading"">
                                        <td colspan = ""1"">Codigo</td>
                                        <td colspan = ""2"">Area</td>
                                        <td colspan = ""2"">Fecha Mov.</td>
                                        <td colspan = ""3"">Tipo Mov.</td>
                                        <td colspan = ""3"">Persona</td>
                                        <td colspan = ""1"">Monto</td>
                                    </tr>" +
                                       tablaHtml
                                      +  
                                "</table>" +                                   
                                "<tr class=\"total\"\">\r\n " +
                                "<td></td>\r\n\r\n" +
                                " <td>Total: $385.00</td>\r\n" +
                                "</tr>\r\n" +
                                "</table>\r\n" +
                                " </div>\r\n" +
                                "</body>\r\n" +
                                "</html>";



        return html;
    }
}
```

I attach the image of how it looks, I put the border in 1 to see why the problem but I couldn't solve it.

[I attach the image of what the pdf looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRBFx.png)

The tests I did was to modify the style but I did not get a result.